ROS Routing Procedure
Good afternoon,
Trying to figure out a routing issue and wondering if anyone can help with procedure or idea behind it.
I have two Mikrotiks via a Wireguard Interface both as PPPoE dial outs, communicating and everything works ok.
Point A is 192.168.0.0/24 Point B is 192.168.5.0/24 WG IP 10.10.10.0/30
On point A there is a PABX system with a SIP trunk with two transports the one that is active on 0.247 ip
and the standby on 0.248 ip.
On point B there is only a SIP trunk that i want transfered to Point A.
What needs to be done is for me to somehow route the providers IP lets say xxx.xxx.16.0/24 back to 0.248 for the trunk to register correctly.
I have added a table FIB named SIP but i am having trouble understanding what to add to the rule and what to the route.
Could someone give some assistance?
Thank you in advance

What is xxx.xxx.16.0/24 precisely? Is it your own address at point B? Is it some remote service's address that point B contacts? Is it something else?

That is the range that the sip provider sends for the account to register. And it should be /21 not /24 sorry
